# Bottom few pixels of text cut off

Tags: html, css

I really can't figure out what's going on in this case. On the multiline pieces of text, the bottom few pixels are cut off.

Comment: Looks fine to me on Firefox. Which browser are you seeing this problem in?

Comment: Looks good in Chrome too.  Perhaps a screen cap will help?

Comment: http://i51.tinypic.com/n6faqg.png Letters like g and y, with bottoms that extend past a certain point.

Comment: Only on the second line, by the way. The first line is fine.

Comment: Please don't post a live link to your code or your question will become obsolete as long as you fix this. Instead, try to reproduce the issue with a narrowed down code in a fiddle or so and also place the code here in order to make your question "standalone"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest fix looks to be this:

Change the `font-size` here from `14px` to `13px`

```
#slidertext h3 {
font-size: 13px;
// other styles
}
```

Works for me in Chrome.

Comment: Using this. Text still looks nice, and doesn't have any complications. Also allows for longer submissions without added complications in the future. Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't actually fix the problem, which is a line-height issue. As noted below setting `line-height: normal;` is the fix

Answer (score 77):

Setting

```
line-height: normal;
```

Worked for me.

Comment: @Reece You should accept this answer so it gets more visibility. It solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

Changing `font-size` and `font-family` is just a workaround. I had same issue. It works well in Firefox however not in Chrome. Check `padding` or `margin` of the input box. It was `padding` in my case. I changed `padding:6px` to `padding:0px 6px;` in my case.

Answer (score 1):

On `#slidertext li` you have `overflow: hidden;` set. You either need to adjust height of the li, you have inline styles setting it to `height: 32px`, turn off overflow, or adjust the font size inside of there.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying `line-height` to the paragraph so it fits whatever `font-size` you are trying to set. In my case `font-size` was 14px, so I set `line-height` to 15px.

Answer (score 0):

As per specific Browsers this kind of issue is related to the Font Family, very often. My solution for text being cut off is to change the font family to `sans-serif` and see if this has any effect. This worked infallibly on any browser I tried it in.

As from what the other threads above are stating... it just might help to adjust line-height and padding, sometimes, but for me, none of these worked in general:

```
max-width: 100%;
min-height: 1.62em;
padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;    
vertical-align: initial;
```

`font-family: initial, sans-serif, serif;` is a good starting point and then you can find a font that plays nice with your theme/site.

Answer (score 0):

This fix mine:

```
letter-spacing: normal;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was `font-kerning`. Its default value is `auto` which means it is using kerning information stored in a font. I changed it to normal and it fixed the issue.

```css
input {
  font-kerning: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> > Most of the cases, if font is cutting off from the bottom, it's means, we are using, please try below if this helps ***overflow:hidden;***
>
> For fixing this issue, please use,

```
overflow-x:hidden;
line-height: according to your style-guide (1/1.5//normal);
```

// You can increase and decrease line depending on your style-guide)

.

Answer (score -1):

Check the size of the sliderwrap, the height attribute may be in conflict with the total text size, and since your overflow is hidden, according to your css property, that might be your issue.

Perhaps fixing it like this:

```
#sliderwrap
{
    height:114;
}
```