# Why is my font getting the top and bottom parts of letters chopped off on my site?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-family

I bought this font.  It installed on my site and I'm using at font face.  It's a .otf font.  How can I get the tops and bottoms of all the letters to appear?  Some are cut off.  www.craftersresale.com

Comment: Works for me in IE10. On which browser are you seeing this?

Comment: Google Chrome Version 28.0.1500.71 m

Comment: works fine in Chrome 27.0.1453.110 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I don't know what is chopped off, but you've got to do something with that huge image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bottom of custom font cut off in Opera and webkit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576807/bottom-of-custom-font-cut-off-in-opera-and-webkit)

Comment: seems to be a problem with the font! when you change it to font-size: 17em; it works.. yeahh i know it's to big :D

Answer (score 0):

try to convert the font to .ttf, .otf, .eot, .woff and .svg files at http://www.font2web.com/

It also creates a CSS file and a demo HTML file to show you how to use webfonts on your website - using CSS @font-face.