# Chrome cuts off parts of type on the left, firefox and IE display fine. Chrome bug?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, dom

I have a regular H3 element with a custom font (Didot from Linotype) in italic style. See:

[image: clipped text]

The issue is that Chrome is clipping parts of the type (such as the descenders and serifs) while other browsers display the type just fine. The H3 is not in any container with hidden overflows.

I've tried (without luck):

- `overflow: visible`
- `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;` (and other values)
- `* { overflow: visible !important; }`
- Other "kerning" tricks out there

The only solution that has appeared to ever work is giving the H3 some left padding... but I feel this is an inappropriate solution as I would then have to shift all contents below headings the same amount to the right.

Thoughts?

Comment: seems there is another container with overflow: hidden. Could you proivde a jsFiddle with regular font, using the exact structure used for the screenshot?

Comment: a fiddle would be nice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the text starts to be cut off when at least one CSS property that promotes the element to [RenderLayer](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome) is applied (e.g. `transform` or `opacity`). So it seems to be the internal problem of the renderer that can't be fixed easily at CSS level. I'd recommend just to add some left padding (and right padding, if necessary) to make all letters fit inside the element boundaries, and compensate these paddings by transform or negative margins.

Comment: This is a great answer and makes sense. We are using translations and opacities.

Comment: I tried to disable these properties one by one with DOM inspector. When the last one of them was disabled, the bug disappeared. So I decided that this may be the reason, since elements with RenderLayer and without it often render a bit differently (sometimes it reminds me the `hasLayout` behavior of old IEs).

Comment: Very nice and interesting answer. Here is a jsFiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/p7wum0bp/3/

Comment: I think I'll use that fiddle to submit a bug report.. maybe we can see what's going on. other browsers don't have an issue :|

Comment: I confirm that @Nico's fiddle demonstrates the problem also in iOS 7 Safari, so the bug is probably somewhere deep in WebKit rendering engine.

Comment: Posted on google product forums: https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/chrome/cBJY1aiWPBw/discussion - Not sure where else it could help to be posted.

Comment: Also posted on CRBugs: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=419787&thanks=419787&ts=1412271687

Answer (score 5):

I fixed a similar issue to this by adding a small text indent

```
    text-indext: 4px;
```

The exact indent value needed will differ depending on the font itself and the size of the font. For emample using [@Nico O jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7wum0bp/7/) adding a 16px text indent fixes the issue.

Comment: this works great when text is aligned left, but it won't work if text is aligned right.  I've tried giving a negative value but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the same rendering issue mentioned here: [Bottom of custom font cut off in Opera and webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576807/bottom-of-custom-font-cut-off-in-opera-and-webkit/)

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8617238/4097933 the css file for your fonts chrome will load the EOT and ignore the following woff,ttf and svg fonts.

```
@font-face{
font-family:"Linotype Didot eText W01";
src:url("/dv2/2/dbcd27d7-e1e4-4757-b144-32def75c2eaa.eot?    d44f19a684109620e4841579a790e818c1a37164efcdf0e038d168bbbe670847e33d73662846b089fb09be21eee584570d77c537 80c9058895373c54fba457480d6ed4c5ba215f67d79aebaaeaeeccdfa718e07c265a761f65012da2ebccc6f4b9c3f5f9&projectId=de149dbb-2608-424a-b0f0-ab02bbf5b45c");
src:url("/dv2/3/6bfc2eb5-d4a7-42d3-a372-305f28511a22.woff?d44f19a684109620e4841579a790e818c1a37164efcdf0e038d168bbbe670847e33d73662846b089fb09be21eee584570d77c53780c9058895373c54fba457480d6ed4c5ba215f67d79aebaaeaeeccdfa718e07c265a761f65012da2ebccc6f4b9c3f5f9&projectId=de149dbb-2608-424a-b0f0-ab02bbf5b45c") format("woff"),url("/dv2/1/b66a964d-58b6-42f1-a3f7-fecb060b2ec3.ttf?d44f19a684109620e4841579a790e818c1a37164efcdf0e038d168bbbe670847e33d73662846b089fb09be21eee584570d77c53780c9058895373c54fba457480d6ed4c5ba215f67d79aebaaeaeeccdfa718e07c265a761f65012da2ebccc6f4b9c3f5f9&projectId=de149dbb-2608-424a-b0f0-ab02bbf5b45c") format("truetype"),url("/dv2/11/0a52b68f-a61f-4fa5-a685-99f557fcd924.svg?d44f19a684109620e4841579a790e818c1a37164efcdf0e038d168bbbe670847e33d73662846b089fb09be21eee584570d77c53780c9058895373c54fba457480d6ed4c5ba215f67d79aebaaeaeeccdfa718e07c265a761f65012da2ebccc6f4b9c3f5f9&projectId=de149dbb-2608-424a-b0f0-ab02bbf5b45c#0a52b68f-a61f-4fa5-a685-99f557fcd924") format("svg");
font-weight:400;font-style:normal;
}
```

Given this try put svg fonts first, then ttf, then wof.

Update:I can not find anything support the idea that Chrome will load EOT font files and therefore ignore the following fonts.

Comment: I've tried different orders of fonts - it doesn't seem to help. I also tried adding the `src:local('☺'),` trick. I confirmed it was loading in the proper order by checking the console network tab. Still gets cut off. Interestingly enough, however, http://typecast.com/preview/fontscom/1012:692325?plan=Custom works just fine (When switching the fonts to linotype italic w01)

Comment: Does Chrome recognize EOT? Isn't EOT supported only by IE? I suppose that if Chrome ignored WOFF etc., the font would not be displayed at all.

Comment: I can't find anything to say that Chrome will load EOT font files.

Comment: By my testing, Chrome will ignore the eot and pick up WOFF/TTF/SVG instead -- whichever comes first.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell if this a bug of chrome, an error in the font or a bug at all.

I tried to recreate the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/p7wum0bp/1/

[image]

As you can see the italic, serif ***j*** is not beeing cut off, as in your image. I guess this can depend on font to font.

As u said, you don't want to give the element a padding, as the headline beeing shiftet away from the rest of the text. As a solution, you may use a combination of padding and margin, to get the text in the right position again. Like here:

```
.b-capa-list-item h3
{
    font-family: "Linotype Didot eText W01";
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0 -10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

With this bit ugly workaround you reach the desired result of:

[image]

---

[With the answer of @Ilya Streltsyn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26149768/3244925) I was able to reprouce the problem in a jsFiddle using the opacity property. **You can watch the behaviour here: http://jsfiddle.net/p7wum0bp/3/**

[image]